# save PostgreSQL data in Parquet format

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, parquet

I'm working a project which needs to generate parquet files from a  huge PostgreSQL database. The data size can be gigantic (ex: 10TB). I'm very new to this topic and has done some research online but did not find a direct way to convert the data to Parquet file. Here are my questions:

1. The only feasible solution I saw is to load Postgres table to Apache Spark via JDBC and save as a parquet file. But I assume it will be very slow while transferring 10TB data.
2. Is it possible to generate a huge parquet file size that is 10 TB? Or is it better to create multiple parquet files?

Hope my question is clear and I really appreciate any helpful feedbacks. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use Apache Sqoop

Comment: How did you solve this task?

Answer (score -2):

Use the [ORC](https://orc.apache.org/) format instead of the parquet format for this volume.
I assume the data is partitioned, so I think it's a good idea to extract in parallel taking advantage of data partitioning.

Comment: The OP is asking for parquet!